# Mule/Apache Derby - convert date retrieved in SELECT query from MM/DD/YYYY to DD.MM.YYYY

Tags: sql, date, mule, derby

I have a Mule application that is retrieving information from an Apache Derby database. One field being pulled is a date in the format MM/DD/YYYY - this field is stored as a VARCHAR(30).

How can I query this table and retrieve the date field in the format DD.MM.YYYY? - note the need to transform the dividers to '.' to '/'. Alternatively, is there is a way I can perform this action using Mule Expression Language? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I usually use java.text.SimpleDateFormat for these sorts of date reformatting tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found to this was to do the transformation in SQL with a series of concatenated substrings:

`SUBSTR(MyDate,4,2) || '.' || SUBSTR(MyDate,1,2) || '.' || SUBSTR(MyDate,7,4)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reformat the date in Mule Configuration and if your date is a Varchar in DB ... you can use Mule set Payload

Comment: Thanks @Anirban. Could you be a bit more specific on what I would do here? An example of the MEL expression would be great. Interested to see if there is a better way of doing this than the answer I've provided.